# How to revert a ViewGroup's handling of TouchEvents after scroll

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a ScrollView (parent) containing a Button (child).
The problem is that on scroll, the parent takes ownership of TouchEvents, and never dispatches those again to its child. Because of that, the Button never receives the UP event, and stays pressed forever.

I need the child to receive UP events after scroll, so either:

- Have the parent dispatch TouchEvents again after scroll (like, on UP)
- Have the parent only listen to Move events, and dispatch the rest (DOWN, UP, etc)

I'm using Xamarin, btw. Thank you.

This simple XAML setup produces the problem:

```
<ScrollView
    Orientation="Horizontal">

    <Button Text="drag me horizontally" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        TextColor="White"
        WidthRequest="500">

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="DefaultStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    </Button>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edited the question to give examples

Comment: Ah, it's a Xamarin.Forms app... that would have been a helpful tidbit, and that you are using the VisualStateManager. In the future please try to provide such important details initially. IOW always provide a MCVE.

Comment: I posted an answer, please try it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by modifying your code as following:

MainPage.xamal:

```
<ScrollView x:Name ="Scroll1"
    Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Button x:Name="TestButton1" Text="drag me horizontally" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        TextColor="White"
        WidthRequest="500">

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="DefaultStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Released">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    </Button>
</ScrollView>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TestButton1.Pressed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(TestButton1, "Pressed");
    };
    TestButton1.Released += (sender, args) =>
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(TestButton1, "Released");
    };
    Scroll1.Scrolled += (sender, args) =>
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(TestButton1, "Released");
    };
}
```